# Can't figure out why numpy.log10 outputs nan?

Tags: python, numpy

So I have an 500k array of floating values. When I am trying to:

```
np.log10(my_long_array)
```

270k numbers getting replaced to nan, and they are not that small. For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: t = -0.055488893531690543

In [3]: np.log10(t)
/home/aydar/anaconda3/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log10
  #!/home/aydar/anaconda3/bin/python3
Out[3]: nan

In [4]: type(t)
Out[4]: float
```

What am I missing?

Comment: See the docs for how negatives are handled.  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the logarithm of a negative number is undefined, hence the `nan`

From the [docs to `numpy.log10`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html):

> Returns: y : ndarray
>
> The logarithm to the base 10 of x, element-wise. **NaNs are returned where x is negative**.

Comment: ahh, it was so obvious. I now feel embarrassed. =)) Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Negative numbers always give undefined log,

The logarithmic function

y = logb(x)

is the inverse function of the exponential function

x = b^y

Since the base b is positive (b>0), the base b raised to the power of y must be positive (b^y>0) for any real y. So the number x must be positive (x>0).

The real base b logarithm of a negative number is undefined.

logb(x) is undefined for x ≤ 0